# The buttons in the display screen change Libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

The problem is visible in the pictures. With 800x600 resolution program everything seems normal. But it is necessary to deploy the program, the buttons are large(big)! If you press the button Screen_2 (there is the same screen) buttons are reduced(small)! How can that be when deploying windows all at once applied, not when you press the button? In general, a week or what I can do with it. Google also has not helped. That's decided to write here maybe someone will be able to help. Spread screens and all of the code:

- [one Screen_1_links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vP8n.png)
- [two Screen_2_links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkw4X.png)

The main class starts with a resolution of 800x600:

```
public class RunGame extends Game {
    public SpriteBatch batch;
    public BitmapFont font;    
    TestCamera camera1;
    TestCamera2 camera2;

    @Override
    public void create() {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        font = new BitmapFont();
        camera2 = new TestCamera2(this);
        setScreen(camera1 = new TestCamera(this));
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        super.resize(width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
       super.render();
    }
}
```

Class first Screen_1:

```
public class TestCamera implements Screen {
    final RunGame runGameTest;
    private Texture backText;
    private Skin skin;
    private Stage stage;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private TextButton buttonNewGame;
    private TextButton buttonOptions;
    private TextButton buttonExit;

    public TestCamera(final RunGame runGameTest) {
        this.runGameTest = runGameTest;
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        backText = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("menu/menuScreen/background.jpg"));
        skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("fonts/uiskin.json"));
        stage = new Stage();

        buttonNewGame = new TextButton("--------", skin, "default");
        buttonOptions = new TextButton("Screen_2", skin, "default");
        buttonExit = new TextButton("--------", skin, "default");

        buttonNewGame.setWidth(200f);
        buttonNewGame.setHeight(50f);
        buttonNewGame.setPosition(50, 240);

        buttonOptions.setWidth(200f);
        buttonOptions.setHeight(50f);
        buttonOptions.setPosition(50, 300f);

        buttonExit.setWidth(200f);
        buttonExit.setHeight(50f);
        buttonExit.setPosition(50, 360f);

        buttonNewGame.addListener(new ClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y){                                
            }
        });
        buttonOptions.addListener(new ClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y){
    ((Game)Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()).setScreen(runGameTest.camera2);               
            }
        });
        buttonExit.addListener(new ClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y){
                Gdx.app.exit();
            }
        });

        stage.addActor(buttonNewGame);
        stage.addActor(buttonOptions);
        stage.addActor(buttonExit);

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0.0f, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        runGameTest.batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        camera.update();
                runGameTest.batch.begin();
                runGameTest.batch.draw(backText, 0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
                runGameTest.font.draw(runGameTest.batch, "FPS: " + Gdx.graphics.getFramesPerSecond(), Gdx.graphics.getWidth()-76, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-20);
                runGameTest.font.draw(runGameTest.batch, "FULL SCREEN: F4 ", Gdx.graphics.getWidth()-150, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-40);
                runGameTest.batch.end();

        stage.act();
        stage.draw();

    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        camera.setToOrtho(false, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        stage.getViewport().update(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), true);
        camera.update();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(null);
        backText.dispose();
        stage.dispose();
        skin.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
    }
}
```

The second Screen_2 is identical to the first! Please help anyone faced this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is resolved - `stage = new Stage(new ScreenViewport());`
And the `camera` had to be moved to the main class!
Thanks to all